# How can i get value from EditText and convert it to int type

Tags: java, android

I've tried to create a simple calculator to calculate the square of the rectangle with 2 sides of it held in EditText. After I press the button, the result should be displayed in the textView. But I couldn't convert the value that I get from the EditText to an `Int` type. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);


    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt1);

    final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt2);

    int num1=0,num2=0;
    final int num3=0;
    String a = editText1.getText().toString();
    String b = editText2.getText().toString();
    num1=Integer.parseInt(a);
    num2=Integer.parseInt(b);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Why did you spam tags? Please only add tags that are actually relevant.

Comment: apart from your code I suggest to wrap it in a `try{}catch(){}` block. The reason for that is that if your text is empty you might face a `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code follow:

```
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt1);

    final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          String a = editText1.getText().toString();
          String b = editText2.getText().toString();
          int num1=Integer.parseInt(a);
          int num2=Integer.parseInt(b);
          int num3 = num1 + num2;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've already done that but in OnClick() i use textView.setText(String c) but num3 is in int type.

Comment: Convert int to String by String.valueOf(num3);